# SOQL Query Understanding

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, query, trailhead

I am currently doing trailhead and in one exercise I saw the following SOQL and I am trying to get an understanding of it.

```
Map<Id,Account> acctsWithOpps = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,(SELECT Id FROM Opportunities) FROM Account]);
System.debug(acctsWithOpps);
```

The above snippet produces the following output

[image]

Basically it displays all the opportunities (if there are any) for an Account.

My question is with respect to the map intialization.

In the map init statement, I do not see any Opportunity object at all.

All it says is `Map<Id, Account>` where are the Opportunity objects here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called a [`Left Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Outer_Join). You are getting your `Opportunity` records in the sub-query:

```
(SELECT Id FROM Opportunities)
```

So each `Account` has a `List<Opportunity>` which you can iterate.

```
for (Account account : [select (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities) FROM Account])
{
    List<Opportunity> childOpportunities = account.Opportunities;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically using this, we can get child objects. You can fetch Opportunities using fetched accounts. See example below

```
Map<Id,Account> acctsWithOpps = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,(SELECT Id FROM Opportunities) FROM Account]);
        System.debug(acctsWithOpps);

for (Account account : acctsWithOpps.values())
{
    List<Opportunity> childOpportunities = account.Opportunities;
    System.debug(childOpportunities);
}
```